# How to select two tables particular attributes only

Tags: mysql

there are two tables

Table 1 
Select EmployeeID (PK),Employeename,employeecompanyid,employeedepartmentid,employeedob,employeepob from table1;

Table 2
Select EmployeeID(PK),LeaveType(PK),LeaveYear(PK),Numberofleavesavailed from table2;

I want to display particular attribute like this query:
the attributes i want to display are
Q.1) EmployeeID,EmployeeName from table1 and EmployeeID.LeaveType,LeaveYear from table2 together in one query

Now my question i want to display Q.1) both in one query.
Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.EmployeeID,t1.EmployeeName,t2.LeaveType,t2.LeaveYear  
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t2.EmployeeID=t1.EmployeeID
```

Basically, join the 2 tables using EmployeeID (which is common to the 2 tables) and select the fields you want from each respective table.

Comment: sir Icarus its displaying only one table thats table one and other table 2 is not displayed.Any help provided.Thanks for your earlier comment,it really helped me.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The query above is an inner join; therefore, only will display records that have matches on BOTH tables. How do you want your output to look? Perhaps if you provide an example of how do you expect to see the output I can help you understand where are you having problems.